# Scalebox label in circuitikz yields an error

Tags: labels, circuitikz

I use `scalebox` to scale the label of a component in `circuitikz`. For example, `to[R,l_=$\scalebox{2}{2\si{\ohm}}$,*-*]` which scales the label with no problem, however, when I try this `to[cV,l^=$\scalebox{2}{2 v_x}$]`, it throws out this error `! Missing $ inserted.`

```
\documentclass[border={5}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[ultra thick,>=latex,american voltages]
\draw
(0,0) to[R,l_=$\scalebox{2}{2\si{\ohm}}$,*-*] (6,0) to[cV,l^=$\scalebox{2}{2 v_x}$] (12,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

I've faced this problem before and I've solved it by placing curly brackets (i.e. `{=}`) but this solution is not working with `v{_}x`.

Comment: Why not `l^=\scalebox{2}{2 $v_x$}`

Comment: @SalimBou, perfect, never thought about it. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then `l^=$\scalebox{2}{2 v_x}$` you can just add `l^=\scalebox{2}{2 $v_x$}`,
also for `l_` you can remove `$` (label does not include superscript or subscript)

```
\documentclass[border={5}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[ultra thick,>=latex,american voltages]
\draw
(0,0) to[R,l_=\scalebox{2}{2\si{\ohm}},*-*] (6,0) to[cV,l^=\scalebox{2}{2 $v_x$}] (12,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```